# Troubleshooting file upload error code 4

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to upload multiple files to my server. If I try to upload a single file, it works fine. but if I try more than one, it gives me an error code 4, even though it does print the name of all the files correctly. Nothing is uploaded. I have the input type set correctly. Can someone help me?

```
Choose Image:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="uploadedfile[]" type="file" multiple="true"/><br /><br /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload Image!" style="margin-left:100px;"/>
```

Below is the code:

```
$i=0;
foreach($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'] as $f)
{
    $file['name'] = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'][$i];
    $file['type'] = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['type'][$i];
    $file['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $file['error'] = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'][$i];
    $file['size'] = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['size'][$i];
    if ($file["error"] > 0)
    {
        echo "Error Code: " . $file["error"];
    }

    $target_path = "uploads/".basename($file["name"]); 

    if(move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $target_path)) 
    {
        echo basename($file['name'])."<br />";
        echo basename($file['tmp_name'])."<br />";
        echo $target_path;

    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
    $i++;
}
```

and my HTML form

```
<div id="album_slider">
    <div style="text-align:center;margin:20px auto;font-size:27px;">Upload Image</div>
    <br style="clear:both;font-size:0;line-height:0;height:0;"/>
    <div style="width:700px;margin:auto;height:250px;text-align:left;">
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST" name="form">
            Image Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="image_name" id="image_name"/><br /><br /><br />
            <input type="hidden" name="a_id" id="a_id" value="<?php echo $a_id; ?>"/>
            Choose Image:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="uploadedfile[]" type="file" multiple="true"/><br /><br /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload Image!" style="margin-left:100px;"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <br style="clear:both;font-size:0;line-height:0;height:1px;"/>
</div>
```

Comment: first thing you should check is the following php.ini directives ... all need to be sufficient to handle the time/memory/filesize required to upload: *max_upload_filesize, max_post_data_size, memory_limit, max_execution_time*

Comment: Value: 4; No file was uploaded. Can we see the complete form you used (html) ?

Comment: Since you're too slow : check your enctype; "multipart/form-data" must be

Comment: @racar - sorry for being late, but I have put the correct enctype. Updated my form. Thanks for the reply tho

Comment: @rdlowrey - They seem to be well within limit - 8M, 8M, 64M and 30. Can there be any other problem ?
Thanks

Comment: Show the code where `$file` is set

Comment: Next test: if you're running PHP > 5.2.12 check the max_file_uploads config setting and make sure it's greater than 1: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
foreach ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
   if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
       echo "$error_codes[$error]";
       move_uploaded_file(
         $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"][$key],
         $target_path
       ) or die("Problems with upload");
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. 
This works. Can you please tell me what I was doing wrong ?
Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Well its going to fail as you want to upload **MULTIPLE** files, but your code is only designed to handle 1 single file.

Go ahead and read through how to handle multiple files here:
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: I believe he's allowed for multiples with this (note multiple attribute): <input name="uploadedfile[]" type="file" multiple="true"/>

Comment: @rdlowrey, yes, but his PHP does not account for handling multiple files hence it is only waiting for 1 single file to save.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying. I THINK (might be wrong) he's simply omitted the start of his loop from the code snippet above judging from how it looks ...

Comment: well if he is omitting it then how am I to know he has it?

Comment: I thought when you hit 4,000 rep you gained the "clairvoyance" privilege :)  Kidding: You're right.

Comment: guys, sorry for the confusion. I had put my whole php code, but I had the php tags in the code, hence it ommited the first few lines and hence the for loop. I removed the php tags and now the whole code is visible.

Answer (score 0):

Use the condition check like below code

```
if(isset($_FILES["qImage"]) && !empty($_FILES["qImage"]["name"])){
        $imgSubQuestion = $_FILES["qImage"];
    }

    if(isset($_FILES["sImage"]) && !empty($_FILES["sImage"]["name"])){
        $imgSolution = $_FILES["sImage"];
    }
```